# Remove parameters with help api?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

How to remove parameters in the method post, from the documentation api. They are created automatically. The client does not need to know about them.
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. It's a POST, not a GET, so why would the client ever see the parameters in question (in the URL, say)? Are you saying you want to exclude data you get back? That's in the control of the API, not the caller. The API would have to support a request that only returns the data you need. If that's not within your control to change, you'll have to simply filter out the data you want when you get the response.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy
No. Here is the post method, a new category is created. I would like to remove the parameters in the post method from the documentation, which are not used. They are used in the get method.

Comment: You could solve this by using a DTO which doesn't have the properties. Are you using Asp.Net HelpPage for documentation?

Comment: @NeverovskiDmitry Please rephrase your question to something like "How do I change the documentation for the API which is stale?" I think that's what you're really getting at. If the API doesn't accept certain properties (or does, but does not respect them), all you need is a documentation change, right?